# How to integrate keycloak authentication in React app?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, keycloak

I have tried to integrate Keycloak authentication in react app. In that authentication was called once the screen refreshed two time. can any any one help me to integrate keycloak with react Js

Answer (score 2):

For a good starting point, see my example repository at GitHub: https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-reactjs-demo
and the linked videos in the readme file.

This approach is used in several projects and approved!

Comment: Thanks, I Will check

Comment: I have done the authentication flow. But while hitting refreshing the screen. Keycloak session was expired. How to handle that? @dasniko